# Ogr_wrap problem

Tags: c#, gdal, ogr2ogr, fwtools

I'm having problems with my csharp project in developing a console application.I've added references of ogr_csharp.dll & osr_csharp.dll & gdal_csharp.dll.

In the line Ogr.RegisterAll(); following error occurs

**Unable to find an entry point named 'CSharp_OLCDeleteField_get' in DLL 'ogr_wrap'.**

I never encountered this problem before while using FwTools 2.4.7 that seems is out of date,so I tried gdal versions 1.9.2 & 1.9.1.

How can i resolve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded only binary packages which I referenced C# libraries from,that had to be compiled entirely before I did.Using those instead,I have installed latest .msi package from [here](http://www.gisinternals.com/sdk) v1.9.2 and it's done as supposed to.